# jQuery datepicker on cloned elements

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to apply a datepicker control to cloned input fields. What I'm doing is finding the table row I want to clone, clone it with `clone(false)` and then for each input with a class `.date` call `datepicker()` on them. The code is as follows:

```
$('.repeat').bind('click', function() {
    var parentEl = $(this).parents('.root');
    var lastRow = jQuery.makeArray($(parentEl).find('.last'));
    var newRow = $(lastRow).clone(false);
    $(lastRow).removeClass('last');
    $(newRow).addClass('last');
    newRow.find('input').each(function() {
        this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(str, p1) {
            return '[' + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + ']';
        });
    }).end().insertAfter($(lastRow));

    newRow.find('.date').each(function() {  
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeYear: true, yearRange: '1970:2010' });
    });
});
```

Now both `$(this).datepicker()` and `$('.date').datepicker()` fail to attach a datepicker control to `input.date`.

The above code works as expected except for the datepicker bit.

Anybody have any ideas?!

Comment: Have you tried attaching them to the DOM first, before applying the datepicker ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There is code that I didn't post that inserts newRow after lastRow (insertAfter($lastRow)) after it does some formatting. I presume that that does attach it to the DOM, or am I mistaken?

Comment: indeed that would add it in the DOM. I posted an answer with an additional change you need to make for the code to work..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems to work if you add the row first (*before applying the datepicker*) and also remove the class added by the datepicker `.hasDatepicker`.

```
$('.repeat').bind('click', function(){
        var parentEl = $(this).parents('.root');
        var lastRow = jQuery.makeArray($(parentEl).find('.last'));
        var newRow = $(lastRow).clone(false, false);
        $(lastRow).removeClass('last');
        $(newRow).addClass('last');
        $('.root').append(newRow); // added this

        newRow.find('.date').each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker'); // added the removeClass part.
            $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeYear: true, yearRange: '1970:2010'});
        });
});
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/LCfC2/

Comment: Gaby, thanks, you made my day! The removeClass() bit did the trick.
This has stumped me since yesterday!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: The key here is to remove the .hasDatepicker class before creating a datepicker on the element. The datepicker will not create if that class already exists!

Comment: Thanks! I never realized that jQuery-ui's datepicker messed with element IDs like that :-S

Answer (score 0):

The class element must be removed and date picker must be then added to the cloned element. Works every time for me no matter whether or not it has been attached to the DOM yet.

```
$(inputData3).removeAttr("class");
$(inputData3).datepicker();
```